# Why does DSE Cassandra is showing full region name in data center name?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am running DSE Cassandra 4.8.14 with 3 nodes cluster on AWS EC2 in us-east-2 region.
I have setup my cassandra.yaml as :

```
...
# You can use a custom Snitch by setting this to the full class name
# of the snitch, which will be assumed to be on your classpath.
endpoint_snitch: Ec2MultiRegionSnitch
...
```

My cassandra-rackdc.properties is as:

```
# When upgrading from SimpleSnitch, you will need to set your initial machines
# to have rack=rack1
dc=DC1
rack=RAC1

# Add a suffix to a datacenter name. Used by the Ec2Snitch and Ec2MultiRegionSnitch
# to append a string to the EC2 region name.
dc_suffix=-2

# Uncomment the following line to make this snitch prefer the internal ip when possible, as the Ec2MultiRegionSnitch does.
# prefer_local=true
```

With this setup, according to [DSE documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureSnitchEC2MultiRegion_c.html), I should see my datacenter name as

```
us-east-2
```

But, in mt system it is showing as **us-east-2-2**

```
nodetool status
Datacenter: us-east-2-2
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.0.0.1    108.55 KB  256     ?       97649498-8521-42e6-b615-408b02d07ff4  2b
UN  10.0.0.2    74.93 KB   256     ?       e7851b9c-1d92-44c7-a20f-3a5f774336c3  2c
UN  10.0.0.3  117.38 KB  256     ?       482c26e6-a438-406d-b601-f5c90d2c5a99  2a

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless
```

Can someone please provide some ideas what I am missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: If all ur nodes are in the same region (us-east-2), why do u need the Ec2MultiRegionSnitch ?

Answer (score 0):

The code to determine the datacenter name is slightly more nuanced that what is described in the documentation.

If the EC2 region ends in `1`, like `us-east-1`, then the datacenter name is `us-east`. However if the EC2 region does not end in `1`, like in your situation with `us-east-2` then it'll use the entire region name as the datacenter name. Adding the *dc_suffix* of `-2`, the datacenter name then becomes `us-east-2-2`.

Why is the naming so inconsistent? There was a bug a long time ago that caused some regions to have the same datacenter name. For example, `us-east-1` and `us-east-2` would both have just been `us-east`. To fix it, the submitter decided to keep only those regions that ended in 1 to use the old datacenter name so that the snitch remains backwards-compatible with existing clusters using the older version.

CASSANDRA-7839 was opened to address standardizing the naming convention for the Ec2Snitch, but it doesn't look like it has progressed as of yet.

Sources:

1. https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/locator/Ec2Snitch.java 

   (Ec2MultiRegionSnitch extends from the Ec2Snitch)
2. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4026

Comment: Great info. Thanks.